# How can i treat 2 different special characters as the same with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [Flexdatalist](https://github.com/sergiodlopes/jquery-flexdatalist) input auto-complete plugin in my site and works fine but i have a weird problem with some special characters.

As i am using the Greek language, every time i enter the letter "ά" for example it returns only the results that contains the letter "α" and not those which contains the letter "ά".

In Greek language the letters "ά" and "α" are exactly the same and i want to treat them as the same character so every time i enter a word that contains the letter "ά" in the search input field to retrieve also the words that contains the letter "α" and vice versa.

Is this even possible with jQuery or Javascript ?

PS. It could be any single HTML5 input field and not just only the specific plug-in i mentioned above.

Comment: It depends on whether Flexdatalist supports special characters. I couldn't tell from the website.

Comment: I would like to do this Independently of the plug-in. For example it could be just an HTML5 <datalist> input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to override the `value` property of an input, so that it performs the replacements of identical-meaning Greek letters whenever you (or whatever plugin) tries to access the `input`'s `value`. I tried to implement such a solution, but it is IMO impossible to achieve. Basically you need to call `Object.defineProperty` on your input and override the `getter` of `value`. However, `input.value` is the **ONLY** way for javascript to access an input's value. That means that once you override the property, you "cut your only way" to the original value. See how my solution falls into an infinite recursion due to this limitation:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(input.value);
});

Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {
  get: function() {
    return this.value.replace(/ά/g, "α")
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />
<button id="myBtn">Read value</button>
```

The "closest" workaround would be to define a custom property and use that all over your code, i.e `greekAmbiguousValue`:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(input.greekAmbiguousValue);
});

Object.defineProperty(input, 'greekAmbiguousValue', {
  get: function() {
    return this.value.replace(/ά/g, "α")
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />
<button id="myBtn">Read value</button>
```

This is far from ideal, because as I said `value` is the only property that gives javascript access to the text inside an input, and every plugin in the world is going to rely on this fact. You would have to customize plugins as well, not just your code to make use of `greekAmbiguousValue`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this should be creating a dictionary or array with accented/unaacented values and then try to parse them. For example:

```
var mySyllabels = {"ά": "α", "á": "a", "ä": "a", "á": "a"};
```

Then create a function that replaces each accented character with their unaccented value.

Comment: thanks for answering @asrom but what i ask here is not replace one character with another but force the input field to treat/understand the 2 different characters as the same. For replacing one character with another i could do something like that:

    $(function() {
    $("#my-input-field").keyup(function() {

    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ά/g, "α"));

But this doesn't solve my problem.